# Loop through all descendants of a node and inspect them one by one

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

I need to make a list of the records in a specific web page. I got the page source in a text file. I need to traverse this node, element by element:

```
HtmlNodeCollection resultContainer = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='result-list divider-y-5']");
```

For each element I need to check the type (div, span, etc.), it's "id" and it's "class" attributes to be able to make my list of records. I don't want a collection of all s or s. That will not help because I don't know which type of element I will face while looping through them. I have to check them all. Because all the data I need are children of the node collection mentioned above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, use LinqToXml instead of xpath ;)
Seriously though, if you need all children of the given xpath expression, can't you just append "/" or "/*" to it? (my xpath is a bit rusty...)

Comment: No I already have all the children there. Now I need to loop through them. I'm looking for a ways to check every element and if it's not what I want go check the next one.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You can enumerate over all nodes in the resultContainer by simply using "foreach(var node in resultContainer)"? Or do you want to enumerate each node's children *for each node from the resultContainer*?

Comment: foreach works. Suppose I have foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in resultContainer). Now I need to check every node's type and attribute. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in resultContainer)
{
    //check node type
    switch(node.Name)
    {
        case "div":
        {
            break;
        }   
        case "p":
        {
        }
        ///....etc
    }

    //get id
    String id = node.Attributes["id"].Value;

    //get class
    String class = node.Attributes["class"].Value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to have the HtmlAgilityPack convert the html document to xml, e.g.:

```
doc.Load(htmlStream, true);
doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
doc.Save(/* your Xml stream or filename */);
```

And then use the regular .NET xml api (e.g. using XmlDocument or XDocument) to process the contents.